# DolphinDB error message when run code in single node

Tags: dolphindb

erroe message when executed in DolphinDB single node
and I had modified the config file

```py
login("admin","123456")
n = 10000000
ID = rand(10,n)
x = rand(1.0,n)
t = table(ID,x)
db= database("dfs://rangedb",RANGE, 0 5 10)
pt = db.createPartitionedTable(t, pt, ID)
```

Comment: error message: openChunks failed to find enough datanodes for write, need 1 datanodes, found 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set dfsReplicationFactor to 2, two datanodes are necessary while creating a partition.
Each datanode should meet the following conditions:

1.It must be online

2.The usage of the volume must be less than 97%.

The error will occur if neither of them meet these two conditions.